# How can I get a text of element with Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

My code return a error. How can I fix this?

(for find XPATH I copy from ctrl+shift+c exactly the element I want)

Code trials:

```
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/mypage')
likes = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, ('//*[@id="facebook"]/head/meta[4])'))
```

Comment: try wrapping both method and string in tuple as such: likes = navegador.find_element((By.XPATH, my_xpath)) then use likes.text

Comment: ('//*[@id="facebook"]/head/meta[4])') should be  '//*[@id="facebook"]/head/meta[4]'

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are using the *Selenium-Python* clients but your `find_element*` line of code is of *Selenium-Java* clients.

---

### Solution

To extract the text your effective line of code will be:

```
likes = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='facebook']/head/meta[4]").text
```

or

```
likes = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="facebook"]/head/meta[4]').text
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```